# Использование --x++ допустимо?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, неопределённое-поведение

#### Есть пара вопросов о допустимости и корректности записи вроде `--x++`

1. Верно ли утверждать, что `(--x)++` представляет собой некоторый эквивалент `(x-1)`? Т. е. верно ли, что этот код корректен и НЕ порождает неопределённое поведение?
2. Почему приходится ставить скобки вокруг декремента? Я ожидал, что без скобок компилятор в конструкции `--x++` сначала возьмёт префиксную операцию, а потом постфиксную, но по какой-то причине он делает наоборот:

   ```
   error: lvalue required as decrement operand
      cout << --x++ << endl;
                ^~
   ```

   Является ли такое поведение компилятора верным?

#### Пример программы: https://ideone.com/q0Wu6U

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int x = 8;
  cout << (--x)++ << endl;
  cout << x << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. По определению, выражение `(--x)++` ведет себя как `(x = x - 1)++`. Начиная с С++17 процесс вычисления оператора присваивания упорядочен (sequenced) очень строго: правая часть полностью упорядочена перед левой частью и сам акт присваивания упорядочен перед вычислением результата оператора присваивания.

   То есть процесс вычисления оператора присваивания `a = b` в С++17 разделили на изолированные друг от друга "отсеки" `[[a] = [b]]`, обрабатываемые справа-налево

   - Сначала вычисляется значение `b` и выполняются все побочные эффекты, присутствующие в `b`
   - Затем вычисляется значение `a` и выполняются все побочные эффекты, присутствующие в `a`
   - Затем происходит собственно присваивание
   - И только после этого результат выражения `a = b` возвращается в контекст более высокого уровня

   Это означает, что случае `(--x)++` неопределенного поведения нет. Все побочные эффекты и чтения значений строго упорядочены относительно друг друга. Это выражение не меняет значения `x`, а его результат - это исходное значение `x` минус `1`.

   В С++14 и ранее ситуация могла быть иной... Например, до C++17 выражение `i = i++` порождало неопределенное поведение, а начиная с C++17 поведение этого выражения [уже полностью определено](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702220/what-made-i-i-1-legal-in-c17/47702440#47702440). Однако в вашем конкретном примере все в порядке и в С++11. Формально в С++98 поведение не определено, но даже это признано дефектом стандарта С++98.

   При этом стоит заметить, что несмотря на довольно строгую упорядоченность, которую С++17 внес в процесс вычисления индивидуального оператора присваивания, вышеупомянутые "отсеки" не гарантируют изолированности процессов вычисления *нескольких* независимых операторов присваивания друг от друга. Выражение `(i = 1) + (i = 2)` по-прежнему порождает неопределенное поведение, потому что побочный эффект `i = 1` не упорядочен относительно побочного эффекта `i = 2`.
2. В С и С++ во все века и времена постфиксные операторы имели больший приоритет, чем префиксные. Поэтому мне не ясно, почему вы ожидали, что `--x++` может быть корректным выражением.

Comment: Что значит "засеквенирован"?

Comment: Тогда получается, что `i = --i + --i` тоже корректно? А классическое `i = ++i + i++`?

Comment: @Cerbo: "Sequenced". Исправил на "упорядочен". Хотя мне кажется, что "упорядочен" не точно передает значение.

Comment: А что значит "является свободным"?

Comment: @AnT,  а  в чем  ошибка моего ответа?

Comment: В С++14 и ранее ситуация не может быть иной

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Это означет что побочный эффект `i++` может произойти в любой момент после вычисления значения `i++`. Он может произойти "рано" - в момент вычисления `i++`. Или он может произойти в любой момент позже: после вычисления `i++`. То есть побочный эффект `i++` может произойти в любой момент процесса вычисления `++i + i++`. А это означет, что он неупорядочен относительно побочного эффекта `++i`.

Comment: Погоди-ка. В `i = --i + --i` по твоим словам `-=` ведёт себя как вычитание с присваиванием. Тогда можно сделать такое: `i = (i-=2) + (i-=3)`, но оно даст разные результаты при вычислении частей в разном порядке. Мне кажется, или это несоответствие? Или мы каким-то образом учитываем одинаковость значения? В любом случае [вот тут](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) утверждается, что `f(i = -1, i = -1);` - это UB, но ведь присваиваемые значения одинаковы.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Во-первых, "разные результаты при вычислении частей в разном порядке" - это *неспецифицированное* поведение, а не неопределенное поведение. Да, в `i = (i-=2) + (i-=3)` результат зависит от порядка, то есть *неспецифицирован*. Но неопределенного поведения тут нет. Во-вторых, `f(i = -1, i = -1)` - это совсем другой пример. Но в С++17 и это тоже не является UB. Ваша ссылка давно устарела. В С++17 выражения-параметры вычисляются по очереди, каждое в своем в изолированном "отсеке".

Comment: Порядок вычисления параметров не определен, но вычисляются они все равно последовательно, изолированно, в *каком-то* линейном порядке. Поэтому для `void f(int, int)` при вызове `f(i = 2, i = 3)` неопределенного поведения нет и гарантируется, что будет вызвано именно `f(2, 3)`, но при этом *неспецифицировано* получит ли в итоге `i` значение `2` или значение `3`.

Comment: @AnT Про `f(int,int)` верно, в про + нет. В С++17, и `--i + --i` и `(i-=2) + (i-=3)` - undefined (если +  не перегружен).

Comment: @Cubbi: Да, вы правы. Я не прав. `--i + --i` и `(i-=2) + (i-=3)` - действительно undefined. Я не подумал о том, что формально `(i-=2)` и `(i-=3)` могут вычисляться "одновременно", так как в `+` они не sequenced относительно друг друга. Побочные эффекты на `i` не упорядочены, поведение не определено.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Я не прав про `(i-=2) + (i-=3)`. Здесь поведение не определено и в C++17 (см. мой предыдущий комментарий). То есть в `i = ++i + 5` все в порядке в С++17. В `f(i = 2, i = 3)` все в порядке в С++17. А вот `i = --i + --i` и `i = (i-=2) + (i-=3)`, как правильно заметил Cubbi - это UB уже на уровне `+`.

Comment: @Cubbi, перегруженность важна из-за того, что перегруженный оператор рассматривается как вызов функции, а обычное сложение - нет? Какая-то странная логика на самом деле. В чём смысл такого разделения?

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Спрашивать про "смысл такого разделения" можно было бы, если бы такое разделение было "взято с потолка" безо всяких на то предпосылок. Но это не так. Перегруженный оператор - это *действительно* именно вызов функции. Отсюда и разделение получается самым естественным образом.

Comment: @AnT, ну как-то не круто, когда код выглядит одинаково, а ведёт себя по-разному...

Answer (score 0):

Увидев оператор `--` компилятор ожидает обьект, а так как `x++`  возвращает временный обьект, то эта операция становится не действительным. Со скобкой эта проблема отпадает: сначала значение обьекта уменьшается, а потом  для этого же обьекта выполняется оператор `++`

По поводу первого вопроса: не вижу ничего некорректного и нет причин для неопределенного поведения... P.S. Неопределенное поведение  в таких выражениях как  `--x + x--`  из за того, что  стандарт не определяет порядок вычисления операндов(что сначала вычислять `--x` или `x--` ? ) В случаи в вопросе, этой проблемы нет.

Comment: Да, действительно, нагуглил, что у постфиксного приоритет больше: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence. А что насчёт UB? Эта часть интереснее.

Comment: Хотя стоп. У них там интересная фраза: _"Стандарт не определяет порядок приоритетов. Они выводятся из грамматики языка."_ - что-то она меня смущает.

Comment: Qwertiy, действительно,  можно запутать с такими вопросами, но  кто понимает, что  (--x)  это ссылька на декрементированный обьект  x, тот поймет,  что применение любого оператора к нему не является UB.    И грамматика языка диктует то, что я описал. Смущаться не стоит

Comment: Но ведь `--x + x--` - это классическое UB. Насколько я понимаю, `--x + --x` - тоже. Тогда почему бы `(--x)++` не быть UB?

Comment: Qwertiy,  Обновил

Answer (score 0):

Будет неопредленное поведение, у вас два изменения в одной [точке следования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Скобки точку не создают.

Comment: Ответ @AnT смотрится более обоснованным. Можешь пояснить, почему считаешь, что он неправильный?

Comment: В С++ больше нет понятия "точка следования". Эта концепция была полностью переработана и заменена на понятия "упорядочен до" (sequenced before) и "упорядочен после" (sequenced after). В данном случае все изменения *упорядочены* относительно друг друга, т.е. никакого неопределенного поведения здесь нет. Ваш ответ был бы формально обоснован с точки зрения "классического" C++98 с его "точками следования", но подход C++98 был признан дефектным (потому его и переработали), поэтому даже с точки зрения С++98 ваша ответ не верен.

Comment: @AnT Про C++98 не понял. Почему с точки зрения С++98 ответ не верен, пусть даже эта точка зрения дефектная.

Comment: Модель вычислений в С++98 была позаимствована прямо из С, вместе с "точками следования". Но быстро выяснилось, что к С++ эта модель напрямую не применима, т.к. в С++ многие операторы возвращают lvalue-результаты (там, где С операторы возвращают rvalue-результаты). Это породило целый ряд дефектов в описаниях таких С++ операторов. Это и было одной из причин отказа от "точек следования" в С++ и перехода к новой модели. Изменения, связанные с дефектами стандарта , применяются ретроактивно, то есть эти изменения распространяются и на С++98 тоже.

Answer (score -1):

1) Приоритет операций:
http://cppstudio.com/post/302/
сначала постфиксный, потом префиксный.
2) Постфиксный инкремент возвращает ссылку на временный объект (rvalue), а префиксный декремент принимает ссылку только на постоянный объект (lvalue).
3) Неопределённого поведения здесь порождать нечему. --x возвращает lvalue (ссылку на х), (--x)++ возвращает rvalue - (копию (--x)) + 1. Операция вывода с rvalue объектами работает.
Более того, если включить оптимизацию, он этот код заменит прямо на х-1:

```
int square(int num) {
    return (--num)++;
}
```

gcc9.1 -O2

```
leal    -1(%rdi), %eax
ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rq1uA-

Comment: Эм.. ты тут lvalue с rvalue путаешь... А конкретные действия компилятора - это не доказательство. // Минус не мой.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это я могу). Поправил.