# Почему приоритет постфиксного инкремента больше чем префиксного?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, дизайн-языка

Оказалось, что постфиксные инкремент и декремент имеют более высокий приоритет, чем префиксные ([источник](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)). Правда, там же есть интересная фраза, смысл которой я не очень понимаю: *"Стандарт не определяет порядок приоритетов. Они выводятся из грамматики языка."*

Если посмотреть на запись вида `++x++` и начать выбирать, что же первым хотел использовать программист, то возникает желание поменять эти приоритеты местами и сначала выполнить префиксный. Логика простая: каждый из этих операторов требует lvalue, но только префиксный возвращает lvalue. Получается, вычисление первым постфиксного оператора даёт rvalue и префиксный уже неприменим.

Что я упускаю, и почему приоритеты выбраны именно так?

Не вижу никакого вреда для совместимости с Си, если приоритеты расставить вот так:

[image: скриншот предлагаемых приоритетов]

PS: На основе [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/994872/178988).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Языки С и С++ - разные, но родственные языки, имеющие общие исторические корни и очень схожий фундаментальный синтаксис. Основа грамматики языка С++ пришла из языка С, где так же как и в С++, все *постфиксные* операторы (`[]`, `()`, `++`, `->` и т.п.)  имеют более высокий приоритет, чем все *префиксные* (`*`, `-`, `++` и т.п.)

Ни в языке С, ни в языке С++ нет и никогда не было некоего индивидуального "расставления приоритетов" операторов. Операторы фигурируют в грамматике сразу целыми классами терминальных символов. В данном случае это именно классы *постфиксных* и *префиксных* (aka *унарных*) операторов.

При этом в языке С ваша логика неприменима. Одним из фундаментальных отличий языка С от языка С++ является то, что язык С не старается сохранить lvalue-ность результатов операторов без явной на то необходимости. В языке С и постфиксный, и префиксный `++` возвращает rvalue.

Поэтому ваш вопрос фактически превращается в вопрос о том, почему грамматика С++ не была переделана на основе приведенных вами соображений о том, что в С++ префиксная форма `++` возвращает lvalue. Ответ: потому что приведенные вам соображения не достаточны в качестве основания для такой переделки. Негативный эффект от усложнения грамматики был бы заметен, а позитивный - ничтожен. И это все только ради возможности писать `++x++` вместо `(++x)++`?

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: В С никто и не пытался задавать относительный приоритет двух форм `++`. В С просто существует более общее правило: постфиксные операторы (те, что справа) выше префиксных (тех, что слева). Это правило прекрасно работает в выражениях типа `*f()`, `++a[i]`, `*p->field` и т.п. Никакого "невозможно применить" тут нет - вот они, одновременные применения постфиксных и префиксных - прямо перед вами. Никакой узкоспециализированной направленности на некорректное `++x++` это правило не имеет. Выражение `++x++` попадает под это правило, но это не более чем побочный эффект общего правила.

Comment: Ну для всех постфиксных менять - это прям совсем жесть. Нет, я только о постфиксных инкременте и декременте относительно префиксных. Сейчас табличку сделаю...

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Зачем??? Зачем городить какие-то исключения для `++` и усложнять после этого грамматику, когда есть одно элегантное общее правило??? Оно общее не только для простоты запоминания, оно общее и потому, что все эти операторы сгруппированы именно так в самой грамматике.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос картинку. Ну сишную можно и не усложнять - ей-то без разницы - всё равно эти операторы не конфликтуют, а грамматика плюсов всё равно отличается. Получается что видно как раз то самое "для простоты запоминания". Или неужели настолько сложно распарсить оператор по-другому, что это заслуживает сохранение такого порядка?

Comment: Но `throw` тоже префиксный, а идёт не с остальными префиксными, а стоит предпоследним. И первый `::` вроде вполне инфиксный.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95242/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-ant).

Comment: @vp_arth, помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Так легче для восприятия. Посмотри на таблицу приоритетов, сначала идут все постфиксные операторы, потом все префиксные, потом все бинарные. Убедительной причины делать исключения для `++` и `--`  не было. Нужно буть немного не здоровым, чтобы писать в коде `++x++`.

Comment: Эм.. `throw` ж тоже префиксный, но он предпоследний. Ну и самый первый `::` на постфиксный тоже не похож. И смысл держать delete рядом с new, а не рядом со throw я тоже не уловил.

Comment: Хм.. Я тут ещё про `&x++` подумал, но нет, тут бы фигня получилась - не надо его трогать :) Так что пожалуй да, вся польза ограничивается сомнительными `++x++`.

Comment: @ Qwertiy, исключения делают там, где они необходимы. Было бы странно, если бы `::` не имел максимальный приоритет, а `throw` и `,` минимальный.

Comment: Почему приоритет throw меньше, чем приоритет delete? Из-за этого в выражении `delete[] (a - 50);` приходится ставить скобки, а иначе бы не пришлось. PS: [тут чат появился](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95242/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-ant).